# Deleted question doesn't look deleted in Post Feedback

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, post-feedback

There is [a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221594/2014-so-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire) on [one of the Post Feedback pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback/underrated?filter=all) that is deleted, but it doesn't look like it is (unless you "show full question", and then you can see the red highlight):

> [image]

This question isn't shown as being closed or migrated on MSE, but I was able to find the exact same question, down to the same comments on [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299969/6083675).

Also note that [one of the answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221594/2014-so-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire/221621#221621) appears correctly as deleted on that same page.

Can this be fixed?